# jQuery error: "$ is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a enhanced version of Lightbox called SexyLightbox. It uses jQuery as its framework. When I initialize it, I get this error on regular invervals when the Lightbox isn't running and an infinite amount of times when I attempt to show a picture:

```
Error: $ is undefined
Source File: http://bagelstreet.se/sexylightbox/sexylightbox.v2.3.jquery.min.js
Line: 12
```

The initialization script goes as this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sexylightbox/sexylightbox.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="sexylightbox/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sexylightbox/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="sexylightbox/sexylightbox.v2.3.jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          SexyLightbox.initialize({color:'black', dir: 'sexyimages'});
        });
    </script>
```

**UPDATE** So - I've replaced the library, I'm using the *unpacked* version of sexylightbox. FireBug points out the error on the jQuery.bind() function, specifally on the bolded line:

```
jQuery.bind = function(object, method){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);  
  return function() {
    var args2 = [this].concat(args, $.makeArray( arguments ));  
    return method.apply(object, args2);  
  };  
};
```

jQuery version being used is 1.3.2.

Any thoughts on what might be happening?

**Solved**

Problem was a coding error on SexyLightbox author's code. Used $ on jQuery.bind() before $ is defined.

Comment: pretty obvious you forgot to include jQuery.. :) cheers!

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to read a bit before commenting? :)

Comment: Try clearing you cache completely out Joel...I tested in a few browsers here, all working no JS errors.

Comment: @Nick Craver: cleared the cache, same results.

Comment: may i ask what version is your jQuery?

Comment: @Reigel: jQuery 1.3.2 is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something in sexylightbox.v2.3.jquery.min.js is causing `$` to be set to undefined. If you set a break point before that file loads, `$` is correctly an alias for `jQuery`. I would try loading a version of sexylightbox.v2.3 that hasn't been run through Packer. That way you can properly use Firebug to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Loaded the unpacked version. Error is pointed at jQuery.bind(), as described in the question update.

Comment: I don't know the exact cause, but it seems to be some type of closure issue. Change $.makeArray to jQuery.makeArray in the bind function and it should hopefully work. I think this is a bug on behalf of the sexylightbbox author, since that bind function should use jQuery, not $.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you might need to use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)?

Comment: There are no additional libraries involved.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with `Content-Type`. It seems that `jquery.min.js` isn't responding with a content type but `sexylightbox.v2.3.jquery.js`does: `application/x-javascript`. Can you get those other requests to use `application/x-javascript` ?

Answer (score 0):

how about try to download the files on their demo that works already.

files on their [demo](http://www.coders.me/ejemplos/sexy-lightbox-2/jQuery/):

- [jQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js)
- [sexyLightbox](http://www.coders.me/ejemplos/sexy-lightbox-2/jQuery/sexylightbox.v2.3.jquery.min.js)
- [easing](http://www.coders.me/ejemplos/sexy-lightbox-2/jQuery/jquery.easing.1.3.js)

use the files that is seen to work... maybe it will help you...

Comment: This isn't the first implementation I do of SexyLightbox and I've based my usage of it from that exact demo.

Comment: Okay... well, I can't find any error on your codes... as far as I see it... and the only thing I can think of are the files... I'll try again... uhm do you have it on localhost or you can give us a link sample?...